# Merging csv files using Python

Tags: python, csv

I am starting to learn Python and I would like to merge csv files. I have found the following code :

```
from os import chdir
from glob import glob
import pandas as pdlib

# Produce a single CSV after combining all files
def produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out):
   # Consolidate all CSV files into one object
   result_obj = pdlib.concat([pdlib.read_csv(file) for file in list_of_files])
   # Convert the above object into a csv file and export
   result_obj.to_csv(file_out, index=False, encoding="utf-8")

# Move to the path that holds our CSV files
csv_file_path = 'c:/Users/user/Desktop/DUT1'
chdir(csv_file_path)

# List all CSV files in the working dir
file_pattern = ".csv"
list_of_files = [file for file in glob('*.{}'.format(file_pattern))]
print(list_of_files)

file_out = "ConsolidateOutput.csv"
produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out)
```

But I get those errors when I tried to compile it :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\DUT1\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\DUT1\test.py", line 12, in produceOneCSV
    result_obj = pdlib.concat([pdlib.read_csv(file) for file in list_of_files])
  File "C:\Python\Python385\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 274, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "C:\Python\Python385\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 331, in __init__
    raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.
Furthermore, I would like to remove the headers from all the files except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use-case for which I developed this code chunk. You can try it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
import os

def joinCsvFiles(outFile, dirPath, filePattern="*.csv"):
    dfs = []

    globPattern = os.path.join(dirPath, filePattern)

    fileParts = glob(globPattern)

    for filePart in fileParts:
        df = pd.read_csv(filePart, index_col=False, header=0)
        dfs.append(df)

    print("[!]. Merging {} part files to create a consolidated file\n".format(len(dfs)))
    try:
        finalDf = pd.concat(dfs, sort=False)
        
        finalDf.to_csv(outFile, index=False)

        print ("[>]. Consolidated csv file generated successfully at filepath: '{}'\n".format(outFile))

    except Exception as e:
        raise e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    joinCsvFiles("finalReport.csv", "c:/Users/user/Desktop/DUT1", "*.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help zahid. I tried your code but still get errors about pandas\io\parsers.py and pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx. I forgot to mention that my csv files have headers and some rowshave more columns than others